# MySQLdb connection.py "cant connect" with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, bash

I'm running Django 1.6 with MySQL on [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com). In the bash command line:

- mysqldb has been pip installed
- i can access mysql database from the command line with `$ mysql -h $your_IP =P 3306 -u username -p`

However, when I try and run python manage.py syncdb I get an error that ends with this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.server' (111)")
```

In my django settings I have

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
            'USER': 'myusername',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
            'HOST': 'mysql.server',
            'PORT': '3360',
        }
    }
```

I tried running `python manage.py test and python manage.py testserver` and got the exact same error. I tried python -v manage.py etc to get the verbose spit out and it seems a lot of other stuff is failing to import? Could it be that the settings.py isnt being found? The whole set up worked perfectly fine local, and all I've done is push it to the server and changed the database settings.

Any idea???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings read port as `'PORT': '3360',` change that to `3306`. Also, make sure `mysql.server` is a valid server host. Or it could just be `localhost`

Comment: I did change the string to an integer, thanks. However, its still the same error. I'm trying to get this working on a linux server, and the host says to use exactly: 'mysql.server' . I did have it working with localhost on my computer during dev though!

Comment: It is not the issue of integer v/s string. 3306 and 3360 are not the same.

Comment: Okay. idiot of the year award goes to me! port 3306 vs 3360 was my issue. :embarrased: thats what you get for staying up till 4am last night... Sorry!